# Send multiple base64 to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, base64

I want to send multiple base64 strings via jquery's `$post()`. The number of strings are not always the same. How can I do this and fetch it in php?

Is it a good option to have all strings in an array and add them in `$post()`?

```
var items = [
    "data:image/png;base64,i.....", 
    "data:image/png;base64,i....", 
    "data:image/png;base64,i...."
] //the number od these strings varies on each post
$.post("../send.php",
   {
     for(i=0;i<21;i++){
        'item'+i: items[i]
     }
   },
)
```

php:

```
if($_POST['item1']){
   $item1 = $_POST['item1'];
}
```

Comment: juste execute `$.post("../send.php", items);` and look what you receive in $_POST

Comment: @mmm thanks. But if I do pass them as `items`, how do I assign them in to variables in php?

Comment: have you look what you receive in $_POST ?

Comment: JS :
$.post("../send.php",{items:items});

PHP:
$_POST['items']

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the following steps:

1) Create a form with the input fields that contain all these base64 strings. (the form and all its fields can all be hidden in html)
2) In my form all the input text fields can have the same name like in this case

```
<input type="text" name="text1[]">
```

2) When I need to add a new string, I shall add an input field in that form by using jQuery.append()
3) in my jquery post i will set the data to

```
$.post('../send.php',$('#myFormId').serialize(),function(){
   // what i want to do with the response
})
```

4) in my php page I can easily loop over

```
foreach($_POST['item1'] as $item){
    // do what you want with data
}
```

that's it!

Comment: Looks good but I can not use `serialize(),` coz I'm sending other data. Also Do you mean all base64 in a seperate text field? So will the text fields need to be created dynamically?

Comment: this serialize will only convert your form fields to a json array so that you can receive them in php.
If you want to send multiple base64 strings... i would recommend sending them in a separate text field. so that you can easily read them in php.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would create a regular array of strings, and then iterate to the array of strings and add them as properties of an object using a `for` loop. Here's an example.

```
var items = []; // Empty array.
items.push(item1, item2, item3); // Add Base64 strings.

var postdata = {}; // An object for our postdata.

// Iterate through the array and add items as properties to the object.
for (var _i = 0, _j = items.length; _i < _j; _i++) {
  postdata['item_'+_i] = items[_i]; }

// POST the object to the PHP file.
$.post("../send.php", postdata);
```

Then, in PHP, you get `$_POST['item_1']` until `$_POST['item_n']` from jQuery. :)

## UPDATE

You can process the postdata in PHP like below.

```
<?php

  foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    // Do things for each item POSTED.
    // This will end after the last POSTed item is reached.

    // $k is the 'key', as in what's inside the square brackets of $_POST[]
    // $v is the 'value', as in $_POST[key] = "THIS STUFF";
  }

?>
```

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: thanks. But the issue with your solution is with what I've said in my second sentence.

Comment: There are a number of second sentences. Care to be a little more specific?

Comment: The number of strings are not always the same. So how can I write the `$_POST[]` items in php?

Comment: Updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
JS :  

$.post("../send.php",{items:items}); //send to server

PHP:

$_POST['items'] // catch in server
```